# why to put space between %d and %c while inputting there values using scanf

Tags: c

im a beginner to C,, and i was writing a code to print a square of a user entered character.

usually when we need to input two integers (say x and y) using `scanf()`  we write this `scanf("%d%d", &x, &y)` but according to the needs of my code i am supposed to input one integer (say m) and a character (say ch).

I wrote it as `scanf("%d%c", &x, &ch)` but it has an error, when i execute the program it only asks the integral value to be entered and then it just stop executing.

I searched for this and i found that i need to put space between `%d` and `%c` as `scanf("%d %c", &x, &ch);`

Can anyone explain this why we need to put space between this?

Comment: Read very carefully what `%d`, `%c`, and ` ` (space) do: they each do different, fairly complicated, things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meaning of whitespace characters in the format string (from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf):

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

When your code is:

```
scanf("%d%c", &x, &ch)
```

and you enter

```
10
```

in your console:

1. `10` is read and stored in `x`.
2. the newline character is read and stored in `ch`.

If you use

```
scanf("%d %c", &x, &ch)
```

and you enter

```
10
```

1. `10` is read and stored in `x`.
2. the newline character and other whitespace characters are consumed. The program waits for a non-whitespace character. Once a line of input is entered and at least one non-whitespace character is present in the line, the first non-white character of the line is read into `ch`. This is because `stdin` is typically line buffered.

Comment: "Once a non-whitespace character is entered, it is read into ch." is true except that `stdin` is typically line buffered and `scanf()` will not get the non-whitespace character until a subsequent newline occurs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: @pranav, it's been more than a year and half :) Hope the answer was useful when you asked the question.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all format specifiers in `scanf` automatically skip all whitespace before trying to read anything. That's, for example, how `%d` works (as well as `%s`, `%f` and most other specifiers). However, `%c` is an exception from this behavior. `%c` does not skip whitespace. If your input data contains a whitespace character, `%c` will happily read that character into your `ch` variable.

This is most likely what happens in your case. If you enter

```
5 #
```

to create a 5x5 square of `#`s, the `%d` specifier will read `5` into `x` and stop reading at the space character. Then `%c` will read that space character into `ch`. And then your program will just proceed, leaving the `#` unread. It is quite possible that the rest of your program actually works as intended. It's just that since `ch` is a *space* character, it displays a 5x5 square of *space* characters, which are invisible :) To make your `scanf` in its original form work as intended you have to input your data as

```
5#
```

But a much better way to make sure that your `scanf` actually reads the `#` character into `ch` is to explicitly ask `scanf` to skip all whitespace before reading `ch`. In `scanf` this is done by inserting any whitespace character (space, newline, tab etc.) into the format string. This

```
scanf("%d %c", &x, &ch);
```

will force `scanf` to skip that space after `5` and read the `#` into `ch`. This will also work for inputs like this

```
5              #
```

and even like this

```
5
  #
```

because `scanf` will automatically skip *all* whitespace until it hits the `#`. Note also that even with the updated format sting whitespace in the input is not required, meaning that this input

```
5#
```

will still work with the updated `scanf`.

You can also use these variants

```
scanf("%d\t%c", &x, &ch);
scanf("%d\n%c", &x, &ch);
scanf("%d     %c", &x, &ch);
scanf("%d \n \t %c", &x, &ch);
```

to achieve the same thing. They are all equivalent. The first variant (with a space) just looks better.

Comment: I found this answer to be more informative than the accepted answer. Thank you. +1.