# Why do I keep getting 0 My C Code won't enter Switch

Tags: c, scanf

Write a C program that computes the maximum, minimum, sum and average of 4 integers.

This
program reads 4 integers in decimal, hexadecimal or octal formats and a character that specifies the
math operation (x for maximum, m for minimum, s for sum, a for average) from command prompt
(xterminal on Ubuntu) and prints the result of the operation.

The input/output fomat details are
provided below.

Result should be printed as integer for x, m and s operations; but as a floating point number for the
average (a) operation.

The integer outputs will be printed in hexadecimal format, and the floating
point values will be printed in scientific format.
Input:

```
<number 1>[space] <number 2>[space] <number 3>[space] <number 4>[space] <operation>
```

Sample Input1: 0xFF 99 077 0 s         ,       Expected Output1:0x1a1

Sample Input2:0x10 10 10 010 a         ,   Expected Output2:1.100000e+01

Sample Input3: 0770 0xFF 270 0xAB m    ,      Expected Output3: 0xab

Sample Input4: 010 0x10 10 0x3 x       ,      Expected Output4:0x10

Here's the code I've written

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num1, num2, num3, num4;
  char op;

  scanf("%d%d%d%d%c", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &op);

  switch (op)
  {
  case'x':
    if (num1 > num2&&num1 > num3&&num1 > num4)
      printf("%d", num1);
    else if (num2 > num1&&num2 > num3&&num2 > num4)
      printf("%d", num2);
    else if (num3 > num1&&num3 > num1&&num3 > num4)
      printf("%d", num3);
    else
      printf("%d", num4);
    break;
  case'm':
    if (num1 < num2&&num1 < num3&&num1 < num4)
      printf("%d", num1);
    else if (num2 < num1&&num2 < num3&&num2 < num4)
      printf("%d", num2);
    else if (num3 < num1&&num3 < num1&&num3 < num4)
      printf("%d", num3);
    else
      printf("%d", num4);
    break;
  case's':
    printf("%d", num1 + num2 + num3 + num4);
    break;
  case'a':
    printf(" %f", (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4);
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before the `switch`, you should display what values have been read (with some `printf("%d... %c", ...);`

Comment: the problem may be with the `%d%d%d%d%c` format string.  you are wanting the inputs to be spaced out, but the format string doesn't. (at least for the `%c` part)

Comment: The `op` read the space character between the 4th number and <operation> instead of <operation> character. Try once with eliminating the space between 4th number and <operation> or add space between `%d` and `%c`.

Comment: Also, always check the return value of `scanf` to see whether it parsed all the values you wanted. Otherwise you could be using uninitialized variables.

Comment: Try adding something like this to your switch: `default:printf("Operator %c not recognized!",op);` Most switches need a default statement, if only to alert you to errors.

Comment: As a general rule -- an important one which I strongly recommend to follow -- one should inspect the return values of functions. `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully converted; in your case it should return 5, I think. Does it?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider i believe that the problem is not from `scanf()` not parsing all values given to it, but rather a whitespace character is being read for `%c` instead of the operator

Comment: @Tau ah, I see (I mistook the input example as output example, missing the "Input"). Yeah, probably right. (One should *still* evaluate return values ;-) ).

Answer (score 3):

You need to **add space between %d**'s.Here is a good description why you need [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438718/why-to-put-space-between-d-and-c-while-inputting-there-values-using-scanf) . So the code will become

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %c",&num1,&num2,&num3,&num4,&op);
```

To print in **hexadecimal format** you need to use, "%x" for ex.

```
printf("%x",num1);
```

To print in **scientific format**,use "%.10e"

```
printf("%.10e",num1);
```

One more thing,in order to get a floating point number in division and every number is integer, you need to make at least numerator or denominator floating point.
In your case,

```
printf("%.10e"(num1+num2+num3+num4)/4.0);
```

Comment: `%d` already skips leading whitespace; it's just the `%c` that needs a space before.

Comment: The `%d` operations already skip white space; the spaces between then are not needed.  The space between `%d %c` is crucial; the `%c` (and `%[…]` and `%n`) conversion specifiers do no skip white space.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `printf("0x%2x", op);` after your `scanf()` results in `0x20` being printed out.

`0x20` is the hex value for the space character, thus confirming our suspicions that a whitespace character was being read instead of your wanted operator.

Replacing the format string in `scanf()` (`%d%d%d%d%c`) with `%d%d%d%d %c` causes the method to work properly, since the whitespace character is now ignored before the operator.

Input:  `1 2 3 4 x`

Output:  `4`

Answer (score 0):

As Tau and Toby point out, your `%c` conversion specifier in the `scanf()` call reads the first whitespace character between the last number and the operator.

`%c` is a special case among the conversion operators: Most other conversions skip whitespace by default until they hit a non-whitespace character. That makes sense for user input with line breaks or tabulated text data with varying amounts of whitespace between columns: You want to read the next number or word and are not interested in the spaces.

`%c`, by contrast, simply reads the next character, including spaces etc.; that is useful for do-it-yourself parsing.

There are two easy ways to fix this.

- The less intrusive one is to add some space before the `%c`: `scanf("%d%d%d%d %c", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &op);`. A single space is a "directive" in a format string instructing `scanf`to skip *all* whitespace until a non-whitespace character is found. (See below for a annotated quote from the specification.) Nothing else in the program needs to change.
- You could also read a string with `%s` and inspect its first character. `%s` is intended to read the next word and therefore skips whitespace on its own. But you need to take care of user input which is too long: Neither may it overflow the buffer you are using, nor should it stay in the input and confuse later `scanf`s. We limit the string length to 1 but provide space for 2 characters because `scanf` will terminate the string with a null character. We ignore input which is not read because the program terminates anyway. Example:

  ```
  // ...
  char op[2] = {'\0', '\0'}; // space for the `'\0'`
  // Read a string of length 1 (just a single char, in effect)
  int numScanned = scanf("%d%d%d%d%1s", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, op);
  switch (op[0]) // switch on first char in the array
  {
    case'x':
    // ...
  }
  ```

---

Some review remarks:

`num3 > num1&&num3 > num1&&num3 > num4)` and one other logical expression has two redundant terms (`num3 > num1`).

It would also improve readability to insert spaces between operands and operators which have lesser priority, like this:

`num3 > num1 && num3 > num4)`.

Some people put brackets around the subexpressions even if they are redundant, but I'm not a friend of that.

Last not least your float format conversion in the last `printf` is wrong because the type of the argument expression is `int`; perhaps you would like to cast one int to float? That would cause all ints to be promoted to float and produce a float result:

```
printf(" %f", ((float)num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4);
```

Note that it would not be sufficient to cast the complete result: You would still perform an integer division, rounding down to the lower integer, and then convert that whole number to a float, which is pointless.

---

Quotes about `scanf`, from [the latest ISO C standard draft,](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) 7.21.6.2 (with some formatting and remarks in square brackets):

> The format is composed of zero or more **directives:**
>
> - one or more white-space characters;
> - an ordinary multibyte character (neither % nor a white-space character)
> - or a conversion specification [like %d].

So whitespace characters in the format string (e.g. the space in front of `%c` in my proposed `scanf("%d%d%d%d %c", ...`) are a **directive** like `%d` ... and do what?

> A **directive** composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first nonwhite-space character (which remains unread) [...].

Ah, ok: It skips whitespace and leaves the next character available, which is what we need. :-).